# Parse is crashing after pressing "Ok" button when pushNotification event is received

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

On push event receaved I'm calling:

```
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
```

User is then prompt with an alert, and after pressed on the UIAlertView, app is crashing

PFAlertView.m:

```
+ (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                   message:(NSString *)message
         cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
         otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles
                completion:(PFAlertViewCompletion)completion {
    if ([UIAlertController class] != nil) {
        __block UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                                         message:message

preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

void (^alertActionHandler)(UIAlertAction *) = [^(UIAlertAction *action){
    // This block intentionally retains alertController, and releases it afterwards.
    if (action.style == UIAlertActionStyleCancel) {

    // App is crashing on this line!!

        completion(NSNotFound); 
    //

    } else {
        NSUInteger index = [alertController.actions indexOfObject:action];
        completion(index - 1);
    }
    alertController = nil;
} copy];
```

The app crashes because completion is null.(Parent is NULL)

Did any one else face this problem? what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: For now I'm dealing with the notification myself instead of letting parse do it..

Comment: FYI, Parse fixed this issue in their latest version.